# Component losing the previous state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expandablelistview, react-component, react-state

I'm calling the child component `ExpandableListItem` in a parent component `parentscreen.js`.whenever I clicked on any item of expandable list item it calls the `getAnswer` method and set the state `questionlistarray`.My concern is whenever clicked on any item of expandable list item in child component it always override the previous state  of `questionlistarray` ,but I want previous state shouldn't override and should add to new state.

**parentscreen.js**

```
<View style={{ height: this.state.layout_Height, overflow: 'hidden' }}> {
  this.props.item.sub_Category.map((item, key) => (
  <View style={styles.sub_Category_Text}>
    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}> {item.sub_name} </Text>
    {
    item.name.map((item1, key) => (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 10 }}> {item1.question} </Text>
      <ExpandableListItem                                            
        quesId={item1.question_id}
        assignedToList={ this.props.assignedToList}
        setAnswer={this.getAnswer} />
      {/* {this.renderQuestions(item1.question_id, this.props.assignedToList)} */} </View>
    ))
    } </View>
  ))
  } </View>
```

```
  getAnswer = (obj) => {
        var array = this.state.questionsListArray;
        // AsyncStorage.getItem('qArray').then((value) => {
        //    if (value != null) {
        //      //this.setState({ questionsListArray: value })
        //      // console.log(value)
        //      array = value;
        //    } else {
        //         array = this.state.questionsListArray
        //   }
        // })

        for (var key in obj) {
            var c = array.filter((item) => item.question_id != key)
            c.push(obj[key]);
        }

        c.map((item, key) => (
            console.log("array is " + " " + item.question_id + " " + item.Answer + " " + item.comment + " " + item.assignedTo + " ")
        ))

        // AsyncStorage.setItem('qArray',JSON.stringify(c));
        this.setState({
            questionsListArray: c,
        })
    }
```

Comment: '@anshulsinha' I think you should update your state immutably. What you're doing is, you're trying to update questionsListArray mutably and hence overriding whatever is previously there in the array instead try cloning your previous state first and then push something on to your array.
Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like the below:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      questionsListArray: c
    }));
```

If you are wondering where `prevState` is coming from, React is optionally providing it as. Since `setState`, re-renders the Component, it will not keep the previousState. You need to pass it, explicitly. Hope I helped!

Comment: each item setting the  seperate states.sorry doesn't solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
getAnswer = (obj) => {
    var array = this.state.questionsListArray;

    for (var key in obj) {
        array.push(obj[key]);
    }

    this.setState({
        questionsListArray: array
    })   
}
```

You seem to be filtering out the corresponding question and then push another object into the array, overriding it. I've just removed the filter. Now, it should add to the state and not override anything.